# Removing a file list .xls

Tags: python, list, glob, delete-file, xls

I'm interested in removing .xls files from a list in the glob library,
I want to removing this list by the os library.

Here is my code :

```
import os
import glob


location = "C:\user\Documents\"
file_xls = glob.glob(location + "\*.xls")
os remove(file_xls)
```

And this is my Error message

```
TypeError: remove: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not list
```

Thanks in advance for your answer !

I'm trying to automate a list deletion of .xls file

Comment: Create a for-loop to delete files one by one.

Comment: Thank you so I created a for loop integrating os.remove and it's woks